# Installing Server 2012 User CAL's from MPSA agreement

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, licensing, cal

we have today received confirmation on our new MPSA agreement that our Server 2012 R2 Server and User CAL's have been added.

I have installed the RD Licensing Manager on the 2012 R2 Standard server and activated it. 
When I go to add the CAL's, I do not see MPSA in the list of license types. The only options I have are as follows:

- License Pack (Retail Purchase)
- Open License
- Select License
- Enterprise Agreement
- Campus Agreement
- School Agreement
- Services Provider License Agreement
- Other Agreement
- Select Plus Agreement.

I have tried to enter our agreement number in all of these options but it fails to activate. 
Has anyone else seen this? What am I doing wrong?
Sorry if I am asking this in the wrong place, I never can find the right place :)

Comment: I would first suggest that the best place to ask this question is at Microsoft, which would have been my first action. That being said, I'm assuming that the MPSA program is new and so that option isn't available in the License Manager because Windows Server 2012 R2 pre-dates the MPSA program. You can try to install your CAL's here, where the MPSA program selection is available - https://activate.microsoft.com

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I think you are correct, Microsoft 2012 has not yet been updated to recognise the MPSA agreements so I had to call MS directly and get an activation code. I wish I had known about the site you mentioned above before I had to call MS, would have saved a lot of time and hassle. Thank you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)